# Explicit conversion of leadimages to blobs (migration to Plone4)

Tags: blob, plone

Testing the migration from Plone 3.3 to Plone 4 for a large site resulted in lost leadimages (which have been created with collective.contentleadimage). None of the leadimages are shown and for folder leadimage views the following error occures:

```
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 220, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /opt/Plone4/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.contentleadimage-1.3.0-py2.6.egg/collective/contentleadimage/browser/folder_leadimage_view.pt
   - Line 82, Column 24
   - Expression: <PythonExpr (view.tag(item_object, css_class='tileImage'))>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <ATTopic at /portalok/lutheran/aktualis/aktualis>,
       'context': <ATTopic at /portalok/lutheran/aktualis/aktualis>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7f93e6c4bae0>,
       'here': <ATTopic at /portalok/lutheran/aktualis/aktualis>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xba65310>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://www.lutheran.hu:9080/portalok/lutheran/aktualis/aktualis/folder_leadimage_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x5f3a810>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <SpecialUser 'Anonymous User'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /opt/Plone4/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.contentleadimage-1.3.0-py2.6.egg/collective/contentleadimage/browser/folder_leadimage_view.pt object at 0xb3f49d0>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0xb255810>}
  Module zope.tales.pythonexpr, line 59, in __call__
   - __traceback_info__: (view.tag(item_object, css_class='tileImage'))
  Module <string>, line 1, in <module>
  Module collective.contentleadimage.browser.folder_leadimage_view, line 30, in tag
  Module Products.Archetypes.Field, line 2558, in tag
  Module plone.app.blob.mixins, line 35, in getScale
  Module plone.app.imaging.traverse, line 52, in getScale
  Module plone.app.imaging.traverse, line 84, in createScale
  Module plone.app.blob.field, line 291, in getFilename
AttributeError: getFilename
```

I assume that leadimages have not been migrated to blobs. In the Plone4 migration log there are no lines regarding leadimage migration.

Is there a way to migrate leadimages explicitly to blobs?

Thanks,

Gabor Bogdanyi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the changelog for version 1.3:

> THIS VERSION ADDS BLOB SUPPORT WHICH BECOMES DEFAULT LEAD IMAGE STORAGE IN PLONE4. MIGRATION TO BLOB IS NOT PREPARED YET! DON'T USE THIS VERSION IF YOU ARE MIGRATING TO PLONE4. IT IS SAFE TO USE IT ON PLONE3 OR PLONE4.

This basically means that you could either:

- try pinning the version to 1.2 and do not use blobs while waiting for someone else to address the issue or,
- write the migration and contribute it back. Have a look into the plone.app.blob migrations to see how it's done. I had contributed an example to do that exact thing, haven't tried it out since p4 is out so your mileage may vary: http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/example.blobattype